# Vue.js dynamic components don't change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-transitions

I'm building a Vue.js based SPA where I want to transition between several parts of the content:

```
<template>
    <transition name="fade">
        <component 
            :is="options[active].type" 
            v-bind="options[active].props"
        />
    </transition>
</template>

<script>
const content = [
    {type: 'ContentHeader', props: {...}},
    {type: 'ContentModule', props: {...}},
    {type: 'ContentModule', props: {...}}
];

import ContentHeader from '...';
import ContentModule from '...';

export default {
    components: {
        ContentHeader,
        ContentModule
    },

    data: () => ({
        active: 0,
        options: content
    })
};
</script>
```

When I change the `active` property from 0 to 1, the dynamic component changes and the transition is triggered. Switching to the last component doesn't, though - it has the same element type as the one before. The component's props are different and are rendered correctly but the transition doesn't realize a change has happened and won't fire.

Any ideas how I could solve that - or for a different approach to combine modules in a transition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the component is reused, there is no fresh instance to swap in and the transition isn't triggered, because the instance/template is reused.  That is the default behavior.  But you can change that by using a unique `key`:

```html
<component 
    :is="options[active].type" 
    v-bind="options[active].props"
    :key="active"
/>
```

Here I'm using the `active` index as a unique identifier to tell Vue to use a fresh instance for each component.

This question often comes up in the context of a router having multiple routes using the same component, and the answer then is to use a `key` as well.

Comment: Thanks, @Dan, that solved the issue. I tried a key before but maybe I used a static value.